# are schemas really shared across instances?

Tags: orientdb

In my tests, I'm spawning up ~100 unique OrientDB instances, all in different `plocal` locations. However, I'm getting exceptions when creating the schema in about ~10% of those databases due to "class already exists" errors.

Should this work? Is there something extra I need to do to force a distinct schema per unique `plocal` instance?

Most importantly, is there a workaround? (e.g. unique JVM per test, try/catch schema generation, etc...)

I raised this ticket as I think this is a bug https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5490 but I could be wrong.

NOTE: I seem to be able to workaround this by ensuring that each integration test runs in a separate JVM. Also, I did a full clean of my entire project which may have cleared out any OrientDB disk caches that were created.

Comment: How do you create this 100 OrientDB instance in plocal?

Comment: with `OrientGraphFactory` see my dev branch https://github.com/fommil/ensime-server/blob/graphpocalypse/core/src/main/scala/org/ensime/indexer/graph/GraphService.scala#L105

Comment: Do you have a test case to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just linked you to my dev branch in the last comment, it reproduces it.

Comment: `mkdir .ensime_cache ; sbt gen-ensime ; sbt core/it:test` outta do it. All you need is https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt

Comment: Is there a shared disk cache or something that persists across JVM sessions?

Answer (score 0):

This is [a feature](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Java-Multi-Threading.html), not a bug :-)